# Redeclare jquery plugin function in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In Wordpress v4.0 file /wp-includes/js/wplink.js line 200, i'd like to enqueue my own js via a WordPress plugin and redefine the function **htmlUpdate** to modify it's functionality. What's the right way to do that?

PS: I'm confortable with enqueing scripts etc. Just need help on how to override the functionality with my own plugin.

```
htmlUpdate: function() {
//... blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'my_custom_method', 9999 );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php',     'my_custom_method', 9999 );

function my_custom_method() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ( function( $ ) {

            if ( typeof wpLink == 'undefined' )
                return;

            // Override the function
            wpLink.htmlUpdate= function () { 
                //... blah blah
            };
        } )( jQuery );
    </script>
   <?php
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for..